# How can I fix flickering transitions in WebKit?

Tags: css, css-transitions, slide, flicker

I wrote a pure CSS3  slideshow, here is it http://jsfiddle.net/chinhvotrung/JQTf4/15/.

However, I have no idea to fix a flickering error that occurs whenever hover out of this.
I used to use backface-visibility for my all selectors but it not working for me.
Please help me

```
div.items > div.my-img > img{ /*Flicker occur by this....*/
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease; }

div.items > div.my-img:hover img{ /*And this....*/
cursor: pointer;
transform:scale(1.5);
-ms-transform:scale(1.5);
-moz-transform:scale(1.5); 
-webkit-transform:scale(1.5); 
-o-transform:scale(1.5);
opacity:0.3; }
```

Comment: I certainly am not experiencing any flicker.  I am experiencing a tiny bit of "chugging" as it moves from left to right and back, but I'm not sure what might cause that.

Comment: Hi everyone,
Please via my demo in chrome browse to see what happen ! in Mozilla it's pretty good with me, but Chrome and i have no answer for this problem

Comment: Sorry, I did use Chrome. No flicker.  Just the "chugging" (a few times a second it momentarily stops and picks back up).  Unfortunately, it's kinda hard to debug this kind of thing, as it depends upon your GPU setup, its drivers, and Chrome settings.

Comment: Sorry Jay,
I don't know exactly word to explain for this, but it seem like what you said above, the problem was occur whenever hover out of slide, can we fix this ?

Comment: And oddly enough, I've tried both your code (and switching to using transforms with translation) and on my old laptop (the same one I used earlier), Mozilla is the browser is producing a lot of flickering!  So it really depends on your setup.  I wish there were a better answer I could give.   I have another newer laptop I could check, where I suspect there might not be any issue, but that's a bit of a hassle at the moment.

Comment: BTW, here's the version using `translate` instead of `left` http://jsfiddle.net/JQTf4/16/ I did it for most browsers but opera, but I don't remember what browsers support keyframes anyway...

Comment: New version... http://jsfiddle.net/JQTf4/17/ ...  I noticed if you don't have to show anything behind the div.items it seems to stutter less... interesting.

Comment: Awsome, thank you so much, i also find out my answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/chinhvotrung/JQTf4/  . btw, i was really grateful to you for helping me overcome this problem.
P/s: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

In my setup, the flickering comes from the animation on left property, not the one on scale and opacity.

I have changed that

```
@-webkit-keyframes myExample {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-900px); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes myExample {
    0% { left: 0; }
    50% { left: -600px; }
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

And, at least for me, it works ok

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/JQTf4/20/)

The pixels moved by in te webkit version where already different between webkit (900) and firefox (600)